# Extract only 3 values from a CSV file using php

Tags: php, csv

I have a csv file with 9500 lines have 10 values in each line.

I want to feed only 3 values from each line to database. How do I achieve this using PHP.

```
1,"Goroka","Goroka","Papua New Guinea","GKA","AYGA",-6.081689,145.391881,5282,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
2,"Madang","Madang","Papua New Guinea","MAG","AYMD",-5.207083,145.7887,20,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
3,"Mount Hagen","Mount Hagen","Papua New Guinea","HGU","AYMH",-5.826789,144.295861,5388,10,"U","Pacific/Port_Moresby"
```

I need only the 1st, 5th and 8th value of each line to be saved to database.

I tried exploding each line, then fetch each value from array and looping through each line. But this took time. I'm looking for a better way.

Comment: Try splitting each line into an array, then save the desired elements by using a subscript

Comment: looking for specific php function that can work faster!

Comment: why u didn't try anything..?

Comment: I tried and got results but it look almost 30 seconds to display the output. I just wanted a better code that can work faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to get each rows data and extract the desired values inside a loop like this:

```
// setup pdo statement and bind parameters outside of the loop
$field1 = "";
$field2 = "";
$field3 = "";
$pdo_stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO <table> VALUES(?,?,?)");
$pdo_stmt->bind_param(1, $field1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$pdo_stmt->bind_param(2, $field2, PDO::PARAM_STRING);
$pdo_stmt->bind_param(3, $field3, PDO::PARAM_STRING);

// try to open the csv file containg the data
$fp = fopen("file.csv", "r");

// loop through each row
while($row = fgetcsv($fp) {

  // store field 0, 4 and 7 from each row
  $field1 = $row[0];
  $field2 = $row[4];
  $field3 = $row[7];

  // insert into database
  $pdo_stmt->execute();
}

// close the file
fclose($fp);
```

Of course the above is only meant as an example and you should check so the file could really be opened and so on. If you are using prepared statements note that you should prepare the statement and bind the parameters **outside** of the loop to increase performance.